# Django view field and rendering data

Tags: html, css, django, web

Is it possible to multiple view field for a single page/template?

as example, suppose I have built site where people can post movie review and see others one as well. Now, I have to add an edit button to the review page and I don't want to let other viewers see that edit option. everyone can only see that edit option when they will be on their own article's page. Can you suggest me how to do that? Still now I have thought to create two different views, one for seeing the review and another one to edit and render them into a single template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood good your questions, sure you can.

You have to secure that the logged user is the owner of the post.
You have to make a condition in your template like:

```
{% if request.user.profile == article.owner %}
        <p>
          <a href="{% url 'edit-article' %}">Edit Article</a>
        </p>
{% endif %}
```

For having multiple views in one template,
You can have a  tag, in wich with the href you call another view, and it will render in the actual page you are.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'edit' %}">Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'my_article' %}">My Post</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

You will have to do something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    {% if request.user.profile == article.owner %}
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'edit' %}">Edit</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'my_article' %}">My Post</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Access Control Concern**:
You should, in your django view (For Ex: view mapped to url 'edit'), must make sure that only the `article.owner` is able to make edits by checking the `request.user`. Otherwise even if other users can't see the button, they will be able to edit the post if they know the url or are able to guess it.

Comment: hi, this questions are for same reason, can you help? [Django_data_rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721768/django-many-to-many-field-data-rendering)  &  [template_condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732318/django-differentiating-between-user-and-template-condtion)