# Django many to many field data rendering

Tags: html, sqlite, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I wanted to create a blog site where an author and editor can both have the edit option and the editors will be assigned by author. Now my model field looks like this :

```
class Editor(models.Model):

name = models.OneToOneField(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)


class Blog(models.Model):


title = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
editor = models.ManyToManyField(Editor, blank=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
article = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

and views.py :

```
def blog(request, pk):


if request.user.is_authenticated:
    blogs = Blog.objects.get(id=pk) //for dynamic url
    editors = Editor.objects.all()

context = {'blogs':blogs,'editors':editors}
return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', context)
```

then I wanted to check if the person who is accessing if author or editor or not, so I written an if condition :

```
{% if request.user.author == blogs.author or blogs.editor %}
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

but unfortunately the edit button can be accessed by everyone. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all.

```
{% if request.user.author == blogs.author or blogs.editor %}
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

In this piece of code, the condition is not very good defined. My suggestion is that you make this in this way:

```
{% if request.user.author == blogs.author or request.user.author == blogs.editor %}
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

This is one suggestion.

Now another posibility is to use JavaScript.

In order to do that, I give you some code example of my own.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var editor = '{{user.author.editor}}'

        if (editor == 'False'){
            document.getElementById('edit').innerHTML = ''
        }
</script>
```

In this code, I'm defining that if the user is not a editor, I will not hide the element (In html) with id 'edit'. So in your template, set an id to your element.

```
<a id="edit" href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
```

For this, you will have to set a boolean field in your model.
You can do it like this:

```
class Editor(models.Model):

 name = models.OneToOneField(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
 editor = models.Boolean()
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the javascript code, should be in your template, at the end.

Comment: "In this code, I'm defining that if the user is not a editor, I will not hide the element (In html) with id 'edit'." -- I think I asked for the opposite actually. If the user is an editor of this blog, edit button should appear.

Comment: and another thing is an author can have multiple editors for a blog and each of those editors can have their own article and editors as well. I have asked  [another_question_regarding_this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732318/django-differentiating-between-user-and-template-condtion), please have a look.

Comment: I wrong... I meant that if the user is not a editor, I will hide the element. But ok, I think is not very hard to chnge the logic for what you need, I gave you just some examples of what can you do. There are infinity ways of doing it

Comment: Later I will check your other post. If my answers on this post was helpful, please mark it